# Why was Kylo Ren unable to stop the bowcaster shot from Chewbacca?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

At the beginning of 'Force Awakens', Kylo easily holds a blaster shot in-air, but towards the end, he does not stop Chewbacca's Bowcaster shot.

Why?

Comment: I was not feeling well that day.